# the lowest upper bound of the time complexity

Tags: algorithm

For the following piece of code

```
if ( A > B ){     
  for ( i=0; i<N*4; i++ )         
    for ( j=N*N; j>i; j-- )             
      C += A; 
} 
else {     
  for ( i=0; i<N*N/20; i++ )         
    for ( j=3*N; j>i; j-- ) 
      for ( k=0; k<N*3; k++)
         C += B; 
}
```

what is the lowest upper bound of the time complexity?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: I think the lowest bound would be `O(N^3)`, for the top case.